# If my game has three lives, how do I subtract one life if the player gets an answer incorrect?

Tags: java, subtraction

My game code is linked below. I have a *`static int`* at the top (above the main), called lives, it has a total of three. Later in my game, I want to make it so when the player gets a question wrong, it subtracts a life from the *`int variable`.* Is it possible that I can do such a thing? I am later going to have a *`while loop`* that will recognize when they run out of lives, and end the code. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
package simon_4_randomgame;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Simon_4_RandomGame {

    static String username;
    static int lives = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a username.");
        username = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Hello, " + username + ". Welcome to Fault.");
        System.out.println("As you make your way through this game you will be");
        System.out.println("encountered with a list of faults. In order to win the");
        System.out.println("game, you must fix these problems. Good Luck!");
        System.out.println("");
        sleep(6000);
        System.out.println("This game gives you three lives. Answer something incorrect...");
        System.out.println("Well. There goes a life. Have fun!");
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean this?:  `lives = lives - 1;`

Comment: There you go. @David answered it for you.

Comment: @David I literally laughed out loud.

Comment: `lives--;` If you're in a super hurry and don't have time to type out all of @David's complex code.

Comment: **import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;** is this even possible ?

Comment: @Raf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import

Comment: @SlipperySeal feel sorry for myself. Thanks for the source though.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer because I am a hungry bastXXd that craves for **REPUTATIONS**

When the user answered one wrong, do:

```
lives--;
```

**THERE YOU GO**